# Can´t install R 4.1 on Ubuntu Server 20.04 (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, r

i have a fresh & clean install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 64bit running on my new raspberry pi 4.

The first thing i did was creating a new user with sudo privileges. This was followed by
`sudo update` and `sudo upgrade`.

After that i tried to install R 4.1.0 (latest available R Version). I followed the guide on [this page](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04/) but i´m getting an error on step 3:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.0-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.1.0-1.2004.0) but it is not going to be installed
```

When i run `apt-cache policy r-base*` the (relevant) output is this:

```
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.3-2
  Version table:
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
r-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.1.0-1.2004.0
  Version table:
     4.1.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter4.0/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
     4.0.5-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.4-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.3-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.2-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.1-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     4.0.0-1.2004.0 500
        500 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ Packages
     3.6.3-2 500
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/universe arm64 Packages
```

So the sources should be ok, but they don´t seem to find the r-base-core version 4.1.0 on the r-project repository - apt only finds the official ubuntu release, which is outdated... i don´t know what to do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that your arm64 arch is not supported by the 3rd party repositories.
Evidences are below:

- for *ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0* PPA - [see package search](https://launchpad.net/%7Emarutter/+archive/ubuntu/rrutter4.0/+packages?field.name_filter=r-base&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal) and [file listing](http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter4.0/ubuntu/pool/main/r/r-base/)
- for CRAN [see file listing](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/)

So you have to remove 3rd-party repositories by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:marutter/rrutter4.0
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/"
```

and to continue using R 3.6 from official repositories on your RPi.
Or do fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 which [ships](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/r-base-core) R 4.0 if you are sure about latest R version need.

---

Other option is to compile R 4.1 version locally. You need to enable source code repositories, then download the R source code, compile it and install compiled binaries and other components. Use commands below:

```
sudo sed -i "s/# deb-src/deb-src/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-4/R-4.1.0.tar.gz
tar -xf R-4.1.0.tar.gz
cd R-4.1.0
./configure
make -j9
sudo make install
```

Then you can run this locally installed R version.

Comment: Answer updated with instruction of R 4.1 compilation.

Comment: Thanks - you saved the day :)